# Highlighting data on a map after hoovering on a legend

Tags: d3.js

D3 newbie here.I am trying to target path elements on a map.  When I hover on the legend's I want the corresponding data on the map be highlighted.
Like this.
https://vida.io/documents/jspBB83bm6EvEYE3n

This is what I have so far
http://bricbracs.com/map/

I have managed to target cells in the legend on mouseover. Here is the relevant code from the legend.js code.

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
   var chosen = d.color;
     console.log(chosen)
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue"); 
        })
```

Here is the relevant code from the script.

```
d3.csv("expenses.csv", function(data) {
data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.year == 2014 });
   data.forEach(function(d) {   
    d.value = +d.value; 
  });
        color.domain([
        d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
        d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value })

  ]);

 d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var dataState = data[i].state;
     var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].value);

      for (j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
   jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;    
    if (dataState == jsonState) {
        json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;      
        break;              
    }
   }       
 }
 svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path") 
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke","#ccc")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    value = d.properties.value;                            
             if (value) {
               return color(d.properties.value)
             } else {
              return "#000"
             }
    })

  });
```

What's the best way of achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just mark the pathes with id/class and change color with jQuery. Do you already try?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I managed to solve the problem. I added an id attribute on the path element and changed the fill color from style to attribute so I can reference it later.         d3.selectAll("#states").each(function(d){
    state = d3.select(this);
    if (state.attr("fill") == chosen){
       state.style("stroke","#ccc")
    }

Comment: Jup, easiest solution :) Good job.